# Evaluating call expression

Tags: python-3.x

Below is the expression tree for call expression `mul(add(2, mul(4, 6)), add(3, 5))`.

[image]

---

In the below code,

```
from operator import mul

def square(x):
    print('In square with value: ' + str(x))
    return mul(x, x)

def repeat(f, n):
    def identity(x):
        return x    
    def apply_n_times(x):
        return repeat(f,n-1)(f(x))  
    if n < 0:
        raise ValueError("Cannot apply a function %d times" % (n))
    elif n == 0:
        return identity
    else:
        return apply_n_times
g = repeat(square, 2)(5)    
print(g)
```

How do I evaluate call expression `repeat(f, n-1)(f(x))` in the above code, when `f` is a function, and `n` and `x` are integers.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams when does `f(x)` in `(f(x))`  gets evaluated, before `repeat()` or after `repeat()`? How do I decide that flow?

Comment: Depends on the implementation of the compiler. And it doesn't matter, since neither call has any side effects that affects the other.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams for me, evaluating this expression will enable understand the logic(solution) of this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expressions are evaluated [from left to right](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#evaluation-order) in Python:

> In the following lines, expressions will be evaluated in the arithmetic order of their suffixes:
>
> ```
> expr1, expr2, expr3, expr4
> (expr1, expr2, expr3, expr4)
> {expr1: expr2, expr3: expr4}
> expr1 + expr2 * (expr3 - expr4)
> expr1(expr2, expr3, *expr4, **expr5)
> expr3, expr4 = expr1, expr2
> ```

In this case, that means `return repeat(f, n-1)(f(x))` works like this:

```
tmp1 = repeat(f, n-1)
tmp2 = f(x)
return tmp1(tmp2)
```

...except that it doesn't create those extra variables.

Any reasonable implementation should satisfy these rules, not just CPython.

Comment: Can you please draw expression tree?

Comment: Because as you said `tmp1` will first get evaluated. But as per debug statements `tmp2` is first getting evaluated.`In apply_n_times with: 2 | In square with value: 5 | In apply_n_times with: 1 | In square with value: 25 | 625`. As per your answer, the sequence should be: `In apply_n_times with: 2 | In apply_n_times with: 1|...`

Comment: This is the [flow](https://github.com/shamhub/paradigms_using_python/blob/master/scn.png) I was expecting. Writing `tmp1(tmp2)` does not give this intuition to me.

Comment: I can't make sense of that flow.  It looks like you're evaluating `repeat(square, 1)` and `square(5)` at the same time, but Python generally only does one thing at a time.

Comment: Do you understand the [flow](https://github.com/shamhub/paradigms_using_python/blob/master/scn.png) now?

Comment: No, but I think I understand your confusion.  Try rewriting it into the `tmp` form I showed you and look at your debug output again.  You may be surprised.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to check this is with global variables.

```
tester = 0

def test_1():
    global tester
    print(tester, "from test_1")
    tester = 1
    return lambda x: None

def test_2():
    global tester
    print(tester, "from test_2")
    tester = 2
    return None

test_1()(test_2())
```

and it prints:

```
0 from test_1
1 from test_2
```

in python 3 (and equivalent in 2) with the compiler from [python.org](https://www.python.org/) so it seems to go left to right.

You may have to test it with your compiler to get a result, as it depends on the compiler.

Comment: Python isn't C.  Order of evaluation is well-defined, as shown in my answer.